# Hosting advanced cron for Aegir 3

Tags: cron, aegir

There was one very useful contributed module named Hosting Advanced Cron. It allowed me to set cron interval per site, instead of set just global for all (and you can even disable cron on specific sites). [hosting advanced cron](https://www.drupal.org/project/hosting_advanced_cron)

For Aegir 3, there is no such release and development seemed to be stopped. There is [a fork on Github by omega8cc](https://github.com/omega8cc/hosting_advanced_cron), but it is not functional (doesn't work, has error and notice, has debug statements left on), so does anyone have a solution or a replacement for such a useful feature for Aegir 3?

Comment: The fork from omega8cc is your best bet... it has seen some commits recently. You could open an issue to ask the original maintainer to grant omega8cc access to the project as a co-maintainer.

Comment: Thanks @HermanvanRink I did that already. They reworked module and adjusted for BOA, and it cannot be a drop in replacement for common Aegir. I also confirmed what they said by trying it myself on some instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After discussion with omega8cc, and a bit of testing, the answer is that advanced_cron is not any more compatible with Aegir 3. It is also merged into BOA (by omega8cc) in their core, and it is not back compatible with stand alone Aegir.

There are two options:

- port it to work with standalone Aegir 3
- use crontab and wget / curl to trigger cron on site